# Bounded components of the complement

Tags: gn.general-topology

Hi everyone: Suppose $A\subset \mathbb{R}^{m}$ ($m>1$) is a closed set with empty interior.  Which are the necessary and sufficient conditions that  $A$ have a neighborhood  $V$ such that every bounded component of $
\mathbb{R}^{m}\setminus A$ has a point of $\mathbb{R}^{m}\setminus V$?

Comment: Necessary and sufficient for the existence of such a $V$ is the existence of such a $V$. You need to be more specific.

Comment: What do you mean more specific? The set $A$ is closed and has no interior points.

Comment: I added more conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A$ is compact.  Then necessary and sufficient is that there is some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that every bounded component of $\mathbb R^n \backslash A$ contains a ball of radius $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Correct, but this is not necessary: the union of the spheres $S(n,1/n)$ may have a neighborhood $V$, as explained but the your $\varepsilon$ does not exist. What is the necessary condition?

Comment: @M.Rahmat Unless I misunderstand your notation, that example is not compact.

Comment: You are right, this is why I accepted you partial answer. How about the general case, where $A$ is just closed?